# Why have my likes gone from 192 to 90 in a single mouse click?

Tags: facebook

I am running a contest to increase likes. I logged in to see what my likes were and I had 192—a steady increase I watched all day. I switched from my business page to my personal page and back to my business page and my likes were suddenly at 90.

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: can happen if suddenly people started unliking it for some reason :P

Comment: Nowadays, Facebook are actively discouraging "like-baiting", "share-baiting", and "reaction-baiting" posts.

Answer (score 1):

There is an official (but IMO extremely unconvincing -  and somewhat dated) 'explanation' [here](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10100651578305702):

> Sudden drops in likes can be the result of accounts that are voluntarily deactivated or memorialized. These accounts will be removed from a Page's like count, which makes audience data even more meaningful for your business.
>
> Learn more about ongoing updates to page like counts on our Facebook for Business Page: https://www.facebook.com/business/news/page-likes-update.
>
> You can also follow these instructions to better understand where your Page unlikes came from: https://www.facebook.com/help/536056199791995/?ref=u2u.